# pandas mark rows between events

Tags: pandas, time-series, categories

Create data

```
actions = ['Start','Action1','Action2','Pause','Actoin2','Resume','Action1','Finish','Start','Action1','Finish']
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('14/10/21 09:00:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date_list = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) for x in range(0,11)]
values = [1,1,2,1,2,1,5,1,1,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ActionType': actions,
                   'Timestamp': date_list,
                   'Value': values})
```

| ActionType | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start | 2021-10-14 09:00:00 | 1 |
| Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:01 | 1 |
| Action2 | 2021-10-14 09:00:02 | 2 |
| Pause | 2021-10-14 09:00:03 | 1 |
| Action2 | 2021-10-14 09:00:04 | 2 |
| Restart | 2021-10-14 09:00:05 | 1 |
| Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:06 | 5 |
| Finish | 2021-10-14 09:00:07 | 1 |
| Start | 2021-10-14 09:00:08 | 1 |
| Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:09 | 1 |
| Finish | 2021-10-14 09:00:010 | 1 |

See how there are two "sessions" taking place. I want to mark each session in a new column.

1. How do I get the rows in-between Start and Finish rows? (assume sorted)
2. Similarly, how can I filter-out pauses in the session? For example, to calculate RealTimeElapsed column (or simply make a DuringPause boolean column)

The output should look like this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Session:': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                       'ActionType': actions,
                       'Timestamp': date_list,
                       'RealTimeElapsed': [0,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,0,1,2],
                       'Value': values
                      })
```

| Session | ActionType | Timestamp | RealTimeElapsed | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Start | 2021-10-14 09:00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:01 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | Action2 | 2021-10-14 09:00:02 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | Pause | 2021-10-14 09:00:03 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | Action2 | 2021-10-14 09:00:04 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | Resume | 2021-10-14 09:00:05 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:06 | 4 | 1 |
| 0 | Finish | 2021-10-14 09:00:07 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | Start | 2021-10-14 09:00:08 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | Action1 | 2021-10-14 09:00:09 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Finish | 2021-10-14 09:00:010 | 2 | 1 |

Already considered:

1. Looping: this is a poor practice (my data is very large), but let me know if this is the only feasible solution.
2. Shift: pandas has a shift function, but I only know how to use it for a fixed number of rows, there's no conditional things (e.g. start/finish/pause/resume) I can treat differently
3. Groupby('Type').unstack() and take differences between times: I can't do this because I need to maintain the Value column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
df.insert(0,"Session",np.where(df["ActionType"]=="Start",1,0).cumsum()-1)

def ufunc(df):
    a = list()
    for i,j in df.groupby(df.ActionType.isin(["Start","Pause","Resume"]).cumsum()):
        if j.ActionType.iloc[0] == "Start":
            a.extend(np.array(range(len(j))))
        elif j.ActionType.iloc[0] == "Pause":
            a.extend([max(a)+1] * len(j))
        elif j.ActionType.iloc[0] == "Resume":
            a.extend(np.array(range(len(j))) + max(a))
    return a

df.insert(len(df.columns)-1,"RealTimeElapsed",df.groupby("Session").apply(ufunc).explode().values)

df
```

```
    Session ActionType  Timestamp   RealTimeElapsed   Value
   0    0   Start    2021-10-14 09:00:00    0            1
   1    0   Action1  2021-10-14 09:00:01    1            1
   2    0   Action2  2021-10-14 09:00:02    2            2
   3    0   Pause    2021-10-14 09:00:03    3            1
   4    0   Actoin3  2021-10-14 09:00:04    3            2
   5    0   Resume   2021-10-14 09:00:05    3            1
   6    0   Action1  2021-10-14 09:00:06    4            5
   7    0   Finish   2021-10-14 09:00:07    5            1
   8    1   Start    2021-10-14 09:00:08    0            1
   9    1   Action1  2021-10-14 09:00:09    1            1
   10   1   Finish   2021-10-14 09:00:10    2            1
```

Comment: But what if action3 can occur outside a paused window?

Comment: Can you edit your question ?

Comment: I just changed Action3 to Action2. The point is that actions can occur outside and in-between Pause and Resume actions

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again ?